# Is there any way to "clone" resource in AWS CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I want to create 3 Roles in a CloudFormation stack, BaseRole, Role1 and Role2. Role1 is based on BaseRole but adding one policy, Role2 is adding another policy to Role2.

I'm currently defining the "BaseRole" in each Role, it looks stupid... just wondering is there's any better way to define them, so that Role1 can reference to what's defined in BaseRole and just add the extra policy, and Role2 reference to Role1 then add another policy?

Following is how I currently define these Roles:

```
  BaseRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
            Action:
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
  Role1:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
            Action:
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - !Sub "arn:${AWS::Partition}:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchLogsFullAccess"

  Role2:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
            Action:
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - !Sub "arn:${AWS::Partition}:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchLogsFullAccess"
        - !Sub "arn:${AWS::Partition}:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way would be through [nested stacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-nested-stacks.html):

> As your infrastructure grows, common patterns can emerge in which you declare the same components in multiple templates. You can **separate out these common components** and create dedicated templates for them. Then use the resource in your template to reference other templates, creating nested stacks.

Comment: Thank you Marcin! yes, nested stack is a good way to reuse common components. but I don't think we can define components on top of each other with nested stack. for example if I have a "BaseRole" defined in root stack, in child stack I can refer this "BaseRole", but it's not possible to define "Role1" in child stack with fewer lines then the example above, isn't it?